# how to use sqlite file with android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am stuck in a situation in which I don't know how to use sqlite file in android

1. where to place it? and
2. how we can integrate it?

I know I can fetch it from `data/data/PACKAGE/databases/` folder but when there is a new project I can't find databases folder. where to place my file having extension `.sqlite`.
Any answer will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Reset adb and then check

Comment: See this tutorial: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Answer (score 0):

This maybe could help you i think :
http://zaman91.wordpress.com/2010/09/22/android-how-to-use-own-sqlite-database/

Comment: Thank you Arlem for your answer. I have seen this kind of tutorial but I can't understand that I have created a database using SQLiteManager from Firefox add-on, where I should keep that database file in my project so android can detect that this is database file and another thing is I am not sure if android allows file with .sqlite extension.

Answer (score 0):

if u r using eclipse u can download this plugin just a copy paste of a .jar file :)
Just go through 
this [Link](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/18/sqlitemanager-plugin-for-eclipse/)
and you can see your database in DDMS

Normally Sqlite data are stored in

```
 //data/data/<Your-Application-Package-Name>/databases/<your-database-name>
```

But if you can't see them.
 You can store your database directly in SD card like this:

```
 static class  SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

 SQLiteHelper(final Context context) {
    super(context, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "/DataBase/" + File.separator
            + DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

and now you can see created database in DataBase folder in /sdcard
If you store ur databse in internal memory then you can also copy ur database from internal memory to SD card :)

Comment: Sir I am using SQLite Manager add-on and I have database file having extension .sqlite but I don't know where can I put that file in my project to use it. also want to know if android supports file .sqlite or it require .db

Answer (score 0):

> when there is a new project I can't find databases folder

Reason is security. More accurate if you place your database to internal storage so database is visible only from application that created it. Your .db file is stored in

```
data/data/com.example.db/databases
```

so if you want to open it in another project(that have different package), there won't be your file.

> where to place my file

If you want to achieve and share one db between more applications, you can save file into external storage but now here are issues about security of sensitive data.

But you have also another option. You can share one db for more applications but since this you have to specify **sharedUserId** for each application in your manifest.xml

```
android:sharedUserId="com.example"
```

And then if you want to connect to db from another application you need to use package of hosting application.

```
Context cntxt = this.createPackageContext("hosting.app.package.name", 
                Context.CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the sqlite file in the assets folder of your project and you should copy this file to the desired location on the SD card. Here hope this helps you.

```
public DataBaseHelper(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 300500);// 1? its Database Version
        DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
        this.mContext = context;
    }   

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException
    {
        //If database not exists copy it from the assets

        boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
        if(!mDataBaseExist)
        {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            this.close();
            try 
            {
                //Copy the database from assests
                copyDataBase();
                Log.w(TAG, "createDatabase database created");
            } 
            catch (IOException mIOException) 
            {
                throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
            }
        }
    }
        //Check that the database exists here: /data/data/your package/databases/Da Name
        private boolean checkDataBase()
        {
            File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
            //Log.v("dbFile", dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists());
            return dbFile.exists();
        }

        //Copy the database from assets
        private void copyDataBase() throws IOException
        {
            InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
            String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
            byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
            int mLength;
            while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0)
            {
                mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
            }
            mOutput.flush();
            mOutput.close();
            mInput.close();
        }

        //Open the database, so we can query it
        public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException
        {
            String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            //Log.v("mPath", mPath);
            myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
            //mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
            return myDataBase != null;
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void close() 
        {
            if(myDataBase != null)
                myDataBase.close();
            super.close();
        }



        // Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the database.
       // You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd be easy
       // to you to create adapters for your views.
```